# Mobile application navigation setup

Tags: navigation, tablet, mobile-application

We are making an app to register progress on certain functions, such as delivery on purchase orders or time registration. Everything is registered for a certain project. But we seem to have two types of users:

- registration happens directly per function (via orders, personnel,...)
- registration happens by selecting the project first and doing follow up for a complete project

We are having some doubts about the navigation of the mobile web app:

**1. Function first**

User chooses function at the bottom

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYxux9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**2. Project first**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpEVPg.png)</sup>

We should find some kind of navigation where we can have both views on the same kind of work. We are thinking on something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fav10l.png)</sup>

This is a mobile web app, for both iOS, Android and Win8 users.

Comment: Are you asking what option is the best, or do you have a specific question?

Comment: We'd like to know how one can set up the app navigation to suit both needs? I don't think there is one best option if you have two types of users?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario with web-based and distributed applications. When you have multiple types of users with different needs, a common solution is to provide ways to customize their view of the data. If you have a defined or finite number of views, then this can simply be a toggle or selection. So if someone chooses a Project view then they get the display suited for that, and if someone chooses a Order view then they get the other display. You'll see more complex software application such as Jira or Zendesk that lets you query the data based on filters and save them as 'views' that you trigger (i.e. you trigger the query).